# A power approximation function

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion, approximation

I am trying to construct a function that would approximate $a^b$ using Maclaurin series. Here are my reasoning:

Since
$$a^b=e^{b\ln a}$$

and

$$e^x=\sum^{\infty}_{k=0} \frac{x^k}{k!}$$

it should follow that
$$a^b=e^{b\ln a}=\sum^{\infty}_{k=0} \frac{(b\ln a)^k}{k!}$$

But, when I started to plug in numbers, up to 5 terms, it did appear to give the right answer. Where am I wrong?

**EDIT**
Numbers I tried:

let $x=4\ln3$

$$1+x+x^2/2!+x^3/3!+x^4/4!+x^5/5!=58.39$$

Comment: what numbers did you plug in? Can you show us?

Comment: You are not wrong, but only using the first 5 terms of the series will only produce accurate results when $b\ln a$ is close to zero.  Which numbers did you try?

Comment: If the absolute value of $b\ln a$ is large, you need a lot of terms to get a decent approximation.

Comment: Thanks for your answers! @imranfat, please check the updated version of the question for the numbers I used.

Comment: As you wrote, it is an $infinite$ series; so, if the argument is small, many terms can be required.

Comment: @Artem $4\ln 3$ is a "large" argument. Not _very_ large, but you need more than five terms for a good approximation. You have $\frac{(4\ln 3)^{10}}{10!} \approx 0.74$, so you need the terms up to that to come within $1$ of the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The next term in the expansion has value $\frac{(4 \log 3)^6}{6!}\approx 10$.  You haven't summed enough terms.  It is only when you get to $\frac {x^{10}}{10!}$ that they get below $1$